# Error while using Script Manager

Tags: .net, vb.net, scriptmanager

"Only one instance of a Script Manager can be added to the page. " Such Error occurs when I use Script Manager in my vb.net 2005 application. What should I Do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're using a Master page and you have a ScriptManager placed there while you're adding a new one in a page using the master page.

Whatever reason, the error is caused by the existence of two or more script managers on the page.

It shouldn't be hard to fix. Just check carefully where you have the second script manager that is causing the problem.